# How to make simple basic app in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie in AngularJS. I want two text fields to enter two strings from then press submit button and then get them concatenated and then throw them on the screen.

Comment: You should start by reading angularjs online documentation, you'll find your answer in about 30 minutes and learn much more. You can check "two way datas binding" keywords too... I think that what you looking for ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>String : <input type="text" ng-model="val1" placeholder="Enter somthing here"></p>
<p>String :<input type="text" ng-model="val2" placeholder="enter somthing here"></p>
<button type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<h1>concat String :{{concat}}</h1>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.concat= "";
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.concat=  $scope.val1+""+$scope.val2;
    }
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

sourced from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

I've downvoted this question.

This question is so basic that I'm pretty certain that you haven't tried anything at all. 
This is covered in **every** beginner tutorial you can find on the web, including the basic introductions you'll find at [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and at [angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). And even on the link they post to [codeschool.com](https://www.codeschool.com/pages/angular-1-vs-2).

Follow the codeschool tutorial, write your basic app. If you come into problems, create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and use that ***M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample* to illustrate your question.

Comment: we need StackExchange newbie's so that these questions can go there :

Comment: Indeed. that's why I posted links to some resources, sent a link to the MCVE-page.    
It is also the reason why I explained why I downvoted his question. 
It's not a problem that new people should come to stackoverflow with bad questions, it is a problem if the community doesn't try to educate the newbies on why it is considered a bad question, or on how to improve a question.   
Just like when you start out with maths and make a mistake your grading should reflect that mistake and somebody should try to teach you not to make the same mistake instead of cheering you on for starting.